# How to get numerical suffix from a string?

Tags: c#, string

How to get the number represented by the longest numerical suffix in a string, with readable code without having to write programmingcontest-style algorithm ?

e.g.

```
GetNumericalSuffix("Number=350") => 350, 
"Num-30" => 30
"My21" => 21
```

etc.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you want with this `This-Could be interesting` and `Also-This might 123.45-543.45` or will the number always be suffix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer:

```
var x = "various text 1234";
var digits = x.Reverse().TakeWhile(c => char.IsDigit(c));
var number = new string(digits.Reverse().ToArray());
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var result = int.Parse(new string(input.Reverse()
                                       .TakeWhile(char.IsDigit)
                                       .Reverse()
                                       .ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static int GetNumericalSuffix(string str)
{
    Match match = Regex.Match(str, "[^0-9]*([0-9]+)$");
    if (!match.Success)
        return -1;
    return int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: this should fail on string like: "Num2-30" (there other numbers in the string apart from the suffix itself)

Answer (score 0):

The idea below, code it yourself:

1. Read string as a char array, char by char
2. If `Char.IsDigit(currentChar)` - start filling in an other char array - `numericChars`
3. When `Char.IsDigit() == false` - create string from `numericChars`, then do `Int32.TryParse()`
4. Store number in `List<int>` parsed numbers

Finally you ends up with a list of all found numbers, just find biggest one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with regular expression like this:

```
MatchCollection m = Regex.Matches("Number=350", "\\d+");
int biggestMatch = 0;
foreach (Match match in m)
{
   if (int.Parse(match.Value) > biggestMatch)
   {
      biggestMatch = int.Parse(match.Value);
   }
}
```